# Why doesn't python overwite non-zero arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, logic, blender

```
for k in range(0, popSiz):
    for i in range(0, mn1[0]):
        for j in range(0,mn1[1]):
            theta1[i][j] = random.gauss(0, 1)

    for i in range(0, mn2[0]):
        for j in range(0,mn2[1]):
            theta2[i][j] = random.gauss(0, 1)
    GameLogic.globalDict["theta1-" + str(k)] = theta1
    GameLogic.globalDict["theta2-" + str(k)] = theta2
    theta1 = [[0 for x in range(mn1[1])] for y in range(mn1[0])] # this
    theta2 = [[0 for x in range(mn2[1])] for y in range(mn2[0])] # and this
print(GameLogic.globalDict["theta1-0"]==GameLogic.globalDict["theta1-1"])
```

If I comment the last two lines (where it says `# this` `# and this`) it makes all the `.globalDict["theta1-" + str(k)]`s the same. So it prints true if it's commented and false if it's not. I wonder why is that? I don't get the logic of it.

Comment: in your title, do you mean _Override_ or _Overwrite_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `theta1` and `theta2` lists are objects. Your initial loops *modify* those objects. You then store a reference to those objects in the `globalDict`.

However i you then modify again the same objects obviously all references will point to a modified dictionary. You have to create *new objects* for every iteration in order to avoid this. and that's why adding those two lines make the behaviour change.

Your situation is similar to the simpler:

```
>>> a = []
>>> d = {}
>>> d['a'] = a
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a
[1]
>>> d['a']    # modified because d is actually storing a reference to that list.
[1]
>>> a = []    # now a is a completely different object
>>> a
[]
>>> d['a']   # old reference keep original a value alive.
[1]
```

Also note that it has *nothing* to do with "zeroing" arrays. You can replace your last two lines with:

```
theta1 = [el.copy() for el in theta1]  # or list(el) for el in ...
theta2 = [el.copy() for el in theta2]  # or el[:] for el in ...
```

to achieve the same result, since the next loop will overwrite the values.
(The only difference is that this will not zero out `theta1` and `theta2` in the last iteration...)

---

By the way: you *may* be better off using [`numpy.random.normal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal) to generate arrays of random numbers:

```
>>> numpy.random.normal(size=(5,5))
array([[ 1.16883072, -1.12038842, -0.14351093,  1.20373197,  0.79088439],
       [-0.80960599, -0.56876464,  1.12962452,  0.20582962, -1.36239647],
       [-1.07225523,  0.56895514, -0.07132619,  1.36478187,  0.62836829],
       [ 0.69711124, -0.81957984, -1.27820196,  0.04203822,  1.68618401],
       [-0.54687767,  0.34994992, -0.91724856,  0.2631614 ,  0.08691433]])
```